# How do i create a node in OpenVX Framework to find the FFT(Fast fourier transform) of an image?

Tags: c++, opencv, fft, cimg, openvx

Does anyone know how to create a user-node to calculate the FFT of an image or videoframe using the OpenVXFramework. I want find the FFT values form video frames to calculate the vibration in video frames.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using an FFT library in [OpenCL - clFFT](https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clFFT), [Open CV](https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/dbc/tutorial_py_fourier_transform.html) or [Vulkan -VkFFT](https://github.com/DTolm/VkFFT). Some information on interoperability is available in the [OpenVX Programming Guide](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-816425-9.00019-X) and also in the [Khronos OpenVX tutorial](https://github.com/rgiduthuri/openvx_tutorial).